# css/javascript rotate image around an arc

Tags: javascript, css, html, rotation

Is there any way to rotate images around a circular arc like the one shown in the following image.

I tried:

```
<div id="me_tv_cards">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_6.png" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(-40deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_4.png" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(-35deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_8.png" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(-30deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_9.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_10.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_6.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(21deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_6.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(27deg);">
                            <img src="cards/clubs_6.png" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);">
                        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS `transform:rotate(-40deg);` is only half of the answer.

The other half of the answer is to change the rotation point. This can also be done very easily in CSS using the `transform-origin` style.

In your case, you want something like this:

```
transform-origin: 50% 180px;
```

Where the `50%` is half-way across the width of the card, and `180px` is my guess as to how far down away from the card you want the rotation point. (you'll need to adjust that depending on the size of your graphics)

Hope that helps.

ps -- also note: `-webkit-transform` on its own will only work in Chrome and Safari. You should also specify `-moz-transform`, `-ms-transform` and `transform` in order to target all browsers. (a lot of them don't actually need a prefix at all for this these days anyway though)

Comment: I have no browser restriction. This is building only for chrome

Comment: @Sarah - nevertheless, you should still be careful of using `webkit` prefixes without also specifying the equivalent non-prefixed style; Chrome is likely to drop support for all `webkit` prefixes over the next few versions. Also, designing for a single browser is a bad idea -- that's the exact reason why IE6 is such a big problem today; people wrote sites for IE6 and said "I don't need to support any other browser"... now look at the problems that caused, and ask yourself if you want to be the cause of the same problems all over again in five years time.